# When I do a While Loop, it doesn't work. Nothing appears except what's outside the loop

Tags: python-3.x

When I do a while loop, it doesn't work.

```py
import random

random_number = random.randint(0, 9)
user_number = input("Your number is :")
score = 0

while score > 10:
    if user_number == random_number:
        print("You win !")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("You lose !")
        print("The secret number was : {} and your number was {} !".format(random_number, user_number))
```

Your number is :>? 4
Nothing after

Comment: `score = 0` hence the condition is `False`. Did you mean `score < 10`? Anyway you might want to move the prompt inside the loop otherwise there's not much action.

Answer (score 0):

```
while score > 10: #While score greater than 10
```

Since you have this, and `score = 0`, it means the loop evaluates to false. So it doesn't iterate over the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```py
score = 0
```

Then:

```py
while score>10:
```

Which equals to

```py
while 0>10:
```

Of course it won't run

Comment: try `while score < 10`